# Python 2.5 Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

**Im trying to get this working code from python to work in Google App Engine Launcher, but having trouble possibly with my code. It is working code in python, but for some reason the GAE Launcher will not work right. 
This is the code:**

```
fname = raw_input('Enter your first name: ')
lname = raw_input('Enter your last name: ')
day = int(raw_input("Enter your birth day: "))
month = int(raw_input("Enter your birth month: "))
year = int(raw_input("Enter your full birth year. (eg. 1990): "))

fullname = fname+spc+lname
byear = month+day+year

yrstr=str(byear)
accum1=0
a=yrstr
for b in a:
    x=int(b)
accum1 += x

bnumber=0
accum2=str(accum1)
a=accum2
for b in a:
    x=int(b)
    bnumber +=x


print "Hello", fullname, "I hope you're having a great day!"
print "Your birth number is: ", bnumber
print "According to the birth test, you are:"

if bnumber == 1:
  print """
#1 - THE ORIGINATOR
1's are originals.
Coming up with new ideas and executing them is natural.
Having things their own way is another trait that gets
them as being stubborn and arrogant."""

elif bnumber == 2:
    print """
#2 - THE PEACEMAKER
2's are the born diplomats.
They are aware of others' needs and moods and often think
of others before themselves.
Naturally analytical and very intuitive they don't like to be alone."""

elif bnumber == 3:
    print """
#3 - THE LIFE OF THE PARTY
3's are idealists.
They are very creative, social, charming, romantic, and easygoing.
They start many things, but don't always see them through."""

elif bnumber == 4:
    print """
#4 - THE CONSERVATIVE
4's are sensible and traditional.
They like order and routine.
They only act when they fully understand what they are expected to do.
They like getting their hands dirty and working hard.
They are attracted to the outdoors and feel an affinity with nature."""

elif bnumber == 5:
    print """
#5 - THE NONCONFORMIST
5's are the explorers.
Their natural curiosity, risk taking, and enthusiasm
often lands them in hot water.
They need diversity, and don't like to be stuck in a rut.
The whole world is their school and they see
a learning possibility in every situation."""

elif bnumber == 6:
    print """
#6 - THE ROMANTIC
6's are idealistic and need to feel useful to be happy.
A strong family connection is important to them.
Their actions influence their decisions.
They have a strong urge to take care of others and to help.
They are very loyal and make great teachers.
They like art or music.
They make loyal friends who take the friendship seriously."""

elif bnumber == 7:
    print """
#7 - THE INTELLECTUAL
7's are the searchers.
Always probing for hidden information, they find it difficult
to accept things at face value.
Emotions don't sway their decisions.
Questioning everything in life, they don't like to be questioned themselves.
They're never off to a fast start,
and their motto is slow and steady wins the race."""

elif bnumber == 8:
    print """
 #8 - THE BIG SHOT
8's are the problem solvers.
They are professional, blunt and to the point,
have good judgment and are decisive.
They have grand plans and like to live the good life.
They take charge of people."""

elif bnumber == 9:
    print """
#9 - THE PERFORMER
9's are natural entertainers.
They are very caring and generous, giving away their last dollar to help.
With their charm, they have no problem making friends
and nobody is a stranger to them.
They have so many different personalities that people around them
have a hard time understanding them."""

print
junk = raw_input("Press Enter to exit ")
```

**And the Log file from the GAE Launcher says this:**

```
2012-03-31 18:49:04 Running command: "['C:\\Python25\\python.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--admin_console_server=', '--port=8080', u'C:\\Users\\PCX2\\Desktop\\testengine']"
WARNING  2012-04-01 01:49:06,825 urlfetch_stub.py:111] No ssl package found. urlfetch will not be able to validate SSL certificates.
WARNING  2012-04-01 01:49:06,923 rdbms_mysqldb.py:74] The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
WARNING  2012-04-01 01:49:07,144 dev_appserver.py:3375] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: No module named _imaging
INFO     2012-04-01 01:49:07,164 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:650] Running application dev~birthtest on port 8080: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2012-04-01 01:49:07,164 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:652] Admin console is available at: http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
```

**When I hit browse on the Launcher also this is the error im getting:**

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'> Python 2.5.1: C:\Python25\python.exe
Sun Apr 01 01:54:51 2012
A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.

 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in _HandleRequest(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.DevAppServerRequestHandler instance at 0x03CC8210>)
 2753         outfile = cStringIO.StringIO()
 2754         try:
 2755           self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
 2756         finally:
 2757           self.module_manager.UpdateModuleFileModificationTimes()
self = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.DevAppServerRequestHandler instance at 0x03CC8210>, self._Dispatch = <bound method DevAppServerRequestHandler._Dispat...vAppServerRequestHandler instance at 0x03CC8210>>, dispatcher = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.MatcherDispatcher object at 0x03CCA650>, self.rfile = <socket._fileobject object at 0x03CC3EB0>, outfile = <cStringIO.StringO object at 0x03CCA0C0>, env_dict = {'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~birthtest', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'B6589FC6', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.6.3', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8080', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', ...}
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in _Dispatch(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.DevAppServerRequestHandler instance at 0x03CC8210>, dispatcher=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.MatcherDispatcher object at 0x03CCA650>, socket_infile=<socket._fileobject object at 0x03CC3EB0>, outfile=<cStringIO.StringO object at 0x03CCA0C0>, env_dict={'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~birthtest', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'B6589FC6', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.6.3', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8080', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', ...})
 2641           dispatcher.Dispatch(app_server_request,
 2642                               outfile,
 2643                               base_env_dict=env_dict)
 2644         finally:
 2645           request_file.close()
base_env_dict undefined, env_dict = {'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~birthtest', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'B6589FC6', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.6.3', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8080', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', ...}
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in Dispatch(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.MatcherDispatcher object at 0x03CCA650>, request=<AppServerRequest relative_url: / path: BTGAE.py...mp', mode 'rb' at 0x02DF6F08> force_admin: False>, outfile=<cStringIO.StringO object at 0x03CCA0C0>, base_env_dict={'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~birthtest', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'B6589FC6', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.6.3', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8080', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', ...})
  680         forward_request = dispatcher.Dispatch(request,
  681                                               outfile,
  682                                               base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  683 
  684         if forward_request:
base_env_dict = {'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~birthtest', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'B6589FC6', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.6.3', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8080', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', ...}
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in Dispatch(self=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.CGIDispatcher object at 0x03CBDF70>, request=<AppServerRequest relative_url: / path: BTGAE.py...mp', mode 'rb' at 0x02DF6F08> force_admin: False>, outfile=<cStringIO.StringO object at 0x03CCA0C0>, base_env_dict={'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~birthtest', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 'REQUEST_ID_HASH': 'B6589FC6', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SDK_VERSION': '1.6.3', 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost', 'SERVER_PORT': '8080', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', ...})
 1715                      memory_file,
 1716                      outfile,
 1717                      self._module_dict)
 1718     finally:
 1719       logging.root.level = before_level
self = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.CGIDispatcher object at 0x03CBDF70>, self._module_dict = {'BTGAE': <module 'BTGAE' from 'C:\Users\PCX2\Desktop\testengine\BTGAE.py'>, '__builtin__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__main__': <module 'BTGAE' from 'C:\Users\PCX2\Desktop\testengine\BTGAE.py'>, '_types': <module '_types' (built-in)>, 'bdb': <module 'bdb' from 'C:\Python25\lib\bdb.pyc'>, 'cStringIO': <module 'cStringIO' (built-in)>, 'cmd': <module 'cmd' from 'C:\Python25\lib\cmd.pyc'>, 'codecs': <module 'codecs' from 'C:\Python25\lib\codecs.pyc'>, 'email': <module 'email' from 'C:\Python25\lib\email\__init__.pyc'>, 'email.Charset': <email.LazyImporter object at 0x032480B0>, ...}
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in ExecuteCGI(config=<AppInfoExternal error_handlers=None b...one api_version=1 api_config=None >, root_path=r'C:\Users\PCX2\Desktop\testengine', handler_path='BTGAE.py', cgi_path=r'C:\Users\PCX2\Desktop\testengine\BTGAE.py', env={'APPENGINE_RUNTIME': 'python', 'APPLICATION_ID': 'dev~birthtest', 'AUTH_DOMAIN': 'gmail.com', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'CURRENT_VERSION_ID': '1.1', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', ...}, infile=<cStringIO.StringO object at 0x03CCA4E0>, outfile=<cStringIO.StringO object at 0x03CCA0C0>, module_dict={'BTGAE': <module 'BTGAE' from 'C:\Users\PCX2\Desktop\testengine\BTGAE.py'>, '__builtin__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__main__': <module 'BTGAE' from 'C:\Users\PCX2\Desktop\testengine\BTGAE.py'>, '_types': <module '_types' (built-in)>, 'bdb': <module 'bdb' from 'C:\Python25\lib\bdb.pyc'>, 'cStringIO': <module 'cStringIO' (built-in)>, 'cmd': <module 'cmd' from 'C:\Python25\lib\cmd.pyc'>, 'codecs': <module 'codecs' from 'C:\Python25\lib\codecs.pyc'>, 'email': <module 'email' from 'C:\Python25\lib\email\__init__.pyc'>, 'email.Charset': <email.LazyImporter object at 0x032480B0>, ...}, exec_script=<function ExecuteOrImportScript at 0x03CBFD70>, exec_py27_handler=<function ExecutePy27Handler at 0x03CBFDB0>)
 1619         reset_modules = exec_py27_handler(config, handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
 1620       else:
 1621         reset_modules = exec_script(config, handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
 1622     except SystemExit, e:
 1623       logging.debug('CGI exited with status: %s', e)
reset_modules = True, exec_script = <function ExecuteOrImportScript at 0x03CBFD70>, config = <AppInfoExternal error_handlers=None b...one api_version=1 api_config=None >, handler_path = 'BTGAE.py', cgi_path = r'C:\Users\PCX2\Desktop\testengine\BTGAE.py', hook = <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object at 0x03336270>
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py in ExecuteOrImportScript(config=<AppInfoExternal error_handlers=None b...one api_version=1 api_config=None >, handler_path='BTGAE.py', cgi_path=r'C:\Users\PCX2\Desktop\testengine\BTGAE.py', import_hook=<google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object at 0x03336270>)
 1307 
 1308     if module_code:
 1309       exec module_code in script_module.__dict__
 1310     else:
 1311       script_module.main()
module_code = <code object <module> at 03B4E458, file "C:\Users\PCX2\Desktop\testengine\BTGAE.py", line 7>, script_module = <module 'BTGAE' from 'C:\Users\PCX2\Desktop\testengine\BTGAE.py'>, script_module.__dict__ = {'__builtins__': {'ArithmeticError': <type 'exceptions.ArithmeticError'>, 'AssertionError': <type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>, 'AttributeError': <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, 'BaseException': <type 'exceptions.BaseException'>, 'DeprecationWarning': <type 'exceptions.DeprecationWarning'>, 'EOFError': <type 'exceptions.EOFError'>, 'Ellipsis': Ellipsis, 'EnvironmentError': <type 'exceptions.EnvironmentError'>, 'Exception': <type 'exceptions.Exception'>, 'False': False, ...}, '__doc__': None, '__file__': r'C:\Users\PCX2\Desktop\testengine\BTGAE.py', '__loader__': <google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver_import_hook.HardenedModulesHook object at 0x03336270>, '__name__': 'BTGAE'}
 C:\Users\PCX2\Desktop\testengine\BTGAE.py in ()
    5 
    6 
    7 from appconsole import myprint, printoutput
    8 
    9 def prog_gen(namn=""):
appconsole undefined, myprint undefined, printoutput undefined
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named appconsole
```

Comment: are you getting an error message? if so, please add it to the question. thank you

Comment: This code is structured for use at the command line, and has very little to do with the framework offered by the app engine. Please read the documentation available [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/)

Comment: This code doesn't really have anything to do with GAE. It's just a basic Python console app. The link @jpm provided above is the best resource for learning how to use Python with Google App Engine.

Comment: Im also getting EOF error from using raw_input. Should I be using the Google App enging Interactive console to get this code working on GAE?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an App Engine application; the launcher won't be able to run it as one. For a tutorial on writing App Engine applications, see [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/).

Comment: Where does the python coding come in then? Because I have read that tutorial and Im still confused on exactly what platform to write this code on? SDK console possibly? But that does not use raw_inputs, So its kinda difficult to get this program work at all with GAE.

Comment: @user1302078 App Engine apps are written in Python or Java, but you're trying to run an app designed to run on the console. You can't simply pass that to App Engine and expect it to work - you have to write a webapp, and accept input via HTTP and a forms interface.

Comment: Do I change the code in the Python editor then? Im just confused I'm new at programming, Do you know how to make that code work in GAE? I just feel lost on this. Am I supposed to use Django? Please I would appreciate your help more if you can?

Comment: @JessRajah Start by working your way through the tutorial. Once you understand the basics of writing a webapp - specifically, taking input from a user, and returning output to them - you'll understand how to write a webapp that does what you want. I'd also recommend Charles Severance's "Using Google App Engine".

Comment: Nick I appreciate the book reference. Just having trouble still with my GAE project and my code above. Im using Django for the code now am I at least on the right track?

Comment: @JessRajah I don't mean to offend, but as your code stands now, you're "not even wrong". The way you've written it shows that you don't understand some pretty basic facets of webapp design, such as HTTP's request-based nature, instances, and the data-flow in a webapp. It's not like a client app, where each instance of the app serves only a single user. Until you've taken the time to learn the basics of webapp design, nothing I say is going to give you a quick fix to make it work.